# idangero's angular swiper by Zefoy: not all slides are registered

Tags: javascript, angular, swiper.js

I am trying to use this swiper angular implementation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-swiper-wrapper

```
 <swiper (indexChange)="onIndexChange($event)">
    <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div *ngFor="let images of imageUrls[selectedClass], let i=index" 
          class="swiper-slide">
        <img class="swiper-slide-content" src="{{getImage(i)}}">
      </div>

      <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
      <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    </div>
  </swiper>
```

Now, *the images are all there* - but the swiper only goes from index 0 to 2, so shows three images. I can drag in the fourth image, but it won't transition. If I autoplay, the swiper starts from index 0 after the third image.

I figured it is because of the property childsDiff: 3. 
Furthermore, if I remove the swiper-buttons it can't slide anymore and childsDiff is 1. Why is it not counting the amount of swiper-slides?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly understand why, as I use pretty much what's in the example, but removing the `<div class="swiper-wrapper"> ... </div>` fixed it ...